# override onDraw method for GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps, android-canvas, colorfilter

I am trying to change the colour style of a GoogleMap with a color filter.

To do this, I created a subclass of RelativeLayout inside which I created my map.

I did this with pictures and it worked, but now GoogleMap seems to be painted no matter what I do. I have tried to leave `onDraw` empty and to paint a plain colour after calling to `super.onDraw` but GoogleMap is quite immortal.

The method is being called three times before I see the GoogleMap view with no visible result, and after the map is fully loaded, nothing happens.

Does anyone know how to paint, at least a plain colour over the map by overriding `onDraw`?
Take into account that the aim is to apply a color filter, so I need access to the map image.

Comment: try to override draw(Canvas) method

Comment: thank you! It worked to paint a colour. Lets see if I can do something with the map.

Comment: I can paint now, but it seems like I am not able to get the GoogleMap in a Bitmap... I keep wooking

Comment: To change Google Maps' style like in JavaScript

Comment: AFAIK GoogleMap uses OpenGL layers you can't access yourself to draw the map tiles, so this sounds like a fool's errand. I could be wrong but this is what I remember from looking at ways to programmatically blur parts of the map.

Comment: Any success Mitch in getting bitmap?

Comment: No luck... Maybe with the screen captures every X milliseconds and showing a layer over the map instead; but then you capture the layer next time, not the map.